# how to get d3.transition() to work on dataframes?

Tags: animation, d3.js, transition

The d3.transition() examples I can find are all using simple arrays of numbers (e.g. var data=[1,3,2,4]), and I wonder what's the proper way to bind real data which has a field on pre-transition state and a field on post-transition state. In the sample below, I intend to transition the values from deliciousness column to new column:

> Blockquote

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>D3: Loading data from a CSV file</title>
  </head>
    <body>
    <p>Click on this text to update the chart with new data values (once).</p>
        <script type="text/javascript">

      var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
            w = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
            h = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
      var padding = 40;

      var data = [
        { "Food": "Apples", "Deliciousness": 9, "new":4 },
        { "Food": "Green Beans", "Deliciousness": 5, "new":4 },
        { "Food": "Egg Salad Sandwich", "Deliciousness": 4, "new":4 },
        { "Food": "Cookies", "Deliciousness": 10, "new":4 },
        { "Food": "Liver", "Deliciousness": 2, "new":4 },
        { "Food": "Burrito", "Deliciousness": 7, "new":4 },
      ];

      data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.Deliciousness = +d.Deliciousness;
      });

      var svg = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right + padding)
                        .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left+"," +
                 margin.top+")");

      //initial state
      //scale and axis
      var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
        .domain(d=>d.Food)
        .range([0,w])
        .paddingInner(0.2);
     xScale.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Food; }));

      var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data, d=>d.Deliciousness)])
        .rangeRound([h,0]);


      var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
        .scale(xScale)
        .ticks(5);

      var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
        .scale(yScale)
        .ticks(5);

      //draw rect
      svg.selectAll('rect')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('x',(d,i) => margin.left + i * ((w + 20 ) / data.length))
        .attr('y',d=>yScale(d.Deliciousness))
        .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
        .attr('height',d =>h-yScale(d.Deliciousness))
        .attr('fill',function(d){
          if (d===30) return "red";
          return "rgb(0,0,"+d.Deliciousness*10+")" ;});

      //text label
      svg.selectAll("text")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .text(d=>d.Deliciousness)
        .attr('x',(d,i) => margin.left + i * ((w + 20 ) / data.length) + 0.4*w/ data.length)
        .attr("y", d=>yScale(d.Deliciousness)+15)
        .attr("fill","white")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle");

      //draw axis
      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + ",0)")
        .call(yAxis);

            svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + h + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

      //transition
      d3.select("p")
                .on("click", function() {

         //update scale

      var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data, d=>d.new)])
        .rangeRound([h,0]);


            //Update all rects
            svg.selectAll('rect')
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append('rect')
            .attr('x',(d,i) => margin.left + i * ((w + 20 ) / data.length))
            .attr('y',d=>yScale(d.new))
            .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
            .attr('height',d =>h-yScale(d.new))
            .attr('fill',function(d){
              if (d===30) return "red";
              return "rgb(0,0,60)" ;});



                });


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What/s the best data structure to enable transition: are they different column/fields, or passing in two dataset with same column name?

Comment: transitions are DOM manipulations regardless of the data. maybe start here: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/transition/

Comment: thanks for the resources. I guess what's confusing to me as beginner is how do I pass in the data to the DOM element in its post-transition state? So my question is probably more on data-binding than transition per se. Do I have to type it as var dataset=[2,3,4,5] once for pre-transition state and then var dataset=[2,5,7,9] once again for post-transition state?

Comment: data joins enter/update/exit selections - which all can be transitioned whenever the selection joins new data (ie, changes will be reflected). there is no 'post-transition state.' in the meantime, here's a tutorial on data structures: https://www.dashingd3js.com/data-structures-d3js-accepts